# Max Value of Elements of matrix after certain iterations

Tags: python, numpy, max

I have a 3X3 matrix, then i change the value of each element of matrix using for loop, I need to know that max of each element after some iteration.

```
import numpy as np
U =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5,6,7]]
M=[]
for m in range(0,10):
    for i in range(0,3):
        row=[]
        for j in range(0,3):
            U[i][j]= U[i][j]+2*i+3*j
            row.append(U[i][j])
        M.append(row)
print(np.max(M))
```

currently, np.max giving me the max from the matrix.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can please add input/output?

Comment: So  element [0][0] would be the maximum value M[0][0] ever had?

Comment: Do you realize that `M` will have 10 times as many rows as `U` has?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrong here, but would't the max values after iteration m just be:

```
U + numpy.array([[0,3,6],[2,5,8],[4,7,10]]) * m
```

You don't need to record them if they can be calculated directly.